# Docker farfui не пингует контейнер

Tags: docker, ip, docker-compose, dockerfile

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прописал:

```
$ docker run -d --hostname user --memory 2048mb --memory-swap 2048 \
  --ip 192.168.56.119 --network mv_enp0s8 --restart unless-stopped \
  -v 3cx_backup:/mnt/backup -v 3cx_recordings:/mnt/recordings \
  -v 3cx_log:/var/log -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
  --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add NET_ADMIN --name 3cx farfui/3cx:18.0.0.1880
```

Ping на 192.168.56.119 не проходит.

В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а адрес Вашей машины какой (и подсеть). И с какой машины пингуете

Comment: адресс машины 192.168.56.118 255.255.255.0 пытаюсь пингануть адресс контейнера с машины на которой он стоит.
Я правильно понимаю что так "--ip 192.168.56.119" мы прокидываем ip на контейнер?