# Docker контейнер farfui/3cx:16.0.3.676

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ip, containers

Не проходит ping на контейнер 192.168.56.119.

прописывал ping с виртуальной машины, на которой и стоит докер с изображением:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прописывал:

```
$ docker run -d --hostname user --memory 2048mb --memory-swap 2048mb \
  --ip 192.168.56.119 --network mv_enp0s8 --restart unless-stopped \
  -v 3cx_backup:/mnt/backup -v 3cx_recordings:/mnt/recordings \
  -v 3cx_log:/var/log -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
  --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add NET_ADMIN --name 3cx farfui/3cx:16.0.3.676
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Docker farfui не пингует контейнер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1362816/docker-farfui-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса